# Keeping javascript external - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i keep my javascript/jquery external, my code doesn't work.  but when i combine them in my html file everything is fine.

any suggestions as to why this is?

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
       <script type ="text/javascript" src="program.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="clickme">
    Click here
    </div>

    <img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />

    <p>First Paragraph</p>
    <p>Second Paragraph</p>
    <p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

with external javascript

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
$("p").click(function () {
     $(this).slideUp();
   });
```

VERSUS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

    <div id="clickme">
        Click here
    </div>
    <img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />

    <p>First Paragraph</p>
    <p>Second Paragraph</p>  
    <p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>


    <script>
        $('#clickme').click(function() {
      $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
     // Animation complete.
     });
     });

    $("p").click(function () {
    $(this).slideUp();
     });


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are drastically changing the location of the code in the first version compared to the second. In the second, the code is before the closing body tag after the elements that it is affecting. In the first, the code is in the <head> which is before the elements that it is affecting. Either move the script tags to the location of the second version, or use one of the answers.

Comment: This question would have made sense if you were comparing external & internal but in the same location. -1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess you execute the click event before the DOM finishes loading. Wrap your code inside the dom [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event and it should work, Assuming your path to the external javascript file is correct.

```
$(function(){

   $('#clickme').click(function() {
     $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
       // Animation complete.
     });
   });
   $("p").click(function () {
      $(this).slideUp();
   });
});
```

Always use firebug (console) to see what is wrong with the script, if you run into any script errors.

Comment: why don't you write ".ready" with function?  i read the documentation, but it's still confusing

Comment: @anc1revv The `$(function)` version is just shorter, I prefer the longer `$(document).ready(function)` version because it is easier to read and understand for someone who may be unfamiliar with jQuery.

Comment: @anc1revv As Kevin said $(function(){... is the short form of $(document).ready(handler)... It is nicely written in the ready method documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Your javascript is executed before there are elements on the page. You can get around this by using `$(document).ready(function(){...});` or moving your external javascript files to the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your js code in external file in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //your code goes here

});
```

Right now you are including external js file in header and it is executed. At this point there is no elements so `$('#clickme')` and `$("p")` are empty set. In the second example you run this code after rendering html with that elements.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that there is a difference, is that in the external file your code is executing before the browser has fully parsed the DOM so you are attempting to programatically access elements of the page which the browser is not yet aware of. This is exactly what most people have already said, but let me elaborate a bit further...

Whilst a lot of people have mentioned using jQuery's document ready handler, I would like to point out that a workable solution is simply to move your script tags to the bottom of the page.

Not only will this solve your problem in itself, but it will also improve page load times because of how browsers treat scripts. When the browser encounters a script it stops everything else it is doing (known as a "blocking" operation), and parses and executes the script. This causes the page to just appear to stall from a user's perspective, meaning a bad user experience. Thus, because the scripts are parsed and executed only as they are encountered, by moving your scripts to the bottom you allow the browser to fully render the page so that the JavaScript does not block rendering.

Though rather than *just* moving scripts to the bottom of the page, I'd also follow what the others recommended and wrap the whole code in the document ready handler just to be extra safe that your code will always be executed at the correct time.

Also, in the debate of inline or external, external scripts are generally preferred as they are easier to maintain and the browser can cache them independently of the page (providing the correct HTTP headers are present).

To sum up here's some example code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- all your markup here -->

<!-- script at bottom, markup already rendered by this point -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<!-- inline or external, still wrap in document ready handler -->
<!-- though external is better because the browser can cache it independently of the page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //wrap in document ready to be extra safe
    $(function() { /*code here*/ });
</script>

</html>
```